# ¿"Feedback" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

La palabra inglesa **"feedback"** se usa muy extensamente en castellano para diferentes conceptos:

- Mecanismo por el cual un sistema se alimenta de sí mismo (algo circular).
- Proceso de obtención de respuestas sobre un tema con el que se pretende mejorarlo.

La traducción automática de la primera acepción, la más técnica, es:

> **[realimentación](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=kBvuozPukDXX2YZ12Jul)**
>
> 1. f. Electr. Retorno de parte de la salida de un circuito o sistema a su propia entrada.

Sin embargo, ¿cuál sería una traducción adecuada de la palabra en el segundo contexto? "Realimentación" también suena pertinente, pero parece demasiado técnica.

Así, una frase inglesa del tipo

> Please provide me with some feedback on this topic so that we can
>   improve.

Me sonaría algo forzada con "realimentación", si bien otras opciones como "opiniones", "pensamientos", me gustan pero me parece que son parcialmente correctas por no tener esa connotación de "circularidad".

Comment: **Retroalimentación** es altamente usada para feedback loops. Si quieres destacar que sea positivo o negativo solo adicionas positivo o negativo a retroalimentación. Una alternativa más larga sería "devolver la (palabra)" por ejemplo, información

Comment: Aunque lo correcto es _Retroalimentación_, se puede decir _Feedback_. Lo entiende todo el mundo.

Comment: @MatiasAndina Retroalimentación es muy usada, sí, pero no es una palabra registrada/aceptada y tengo mis dudas de que encaje etimológicamente. Sería mejor usar feedback o realimentación, si quiere emplearse una sola palabra. Lo más acertado sería pedir opiniones/percepciones al respecto.

Comment: @SergioVelásquez Es cierto que no está aceptada por la RAE. También es cierto que la RAE carece de un montón de términos académicos y científicos. Retroalimentación es la traducción literal de feedback y cumple con el propósito a la perfección (al menos en ámbitos técnicos). De todos modos, feedback no siempre es usado en inglés de éste modo. En las respuestas se propusieron alternativas según el uso que se le esté dando.

Comment: @MatiasAndina totalmente cierto. Como mencioné en el comentario anterior, tenía dudas de la etimología de la palabra y resulta ser totalmente válido. En donde trabajo todo el tiempo usan Retroalimentación, ya se que es válido.

Comment: Vale la pena leer Servosistema en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servosistema).  La palabra Reacción aparece en su sentido técnico.  Esta palabra también puede usarse para expresar feedback de un ser humano a la presentación de una idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creo que no hay una palabra en español que recoja a la vez ambos conceptos de la manera que ocurre en inglés. Para el segundo contexto yo usaría `comentarios`, `críticas`, `observaciones` e incluso `opiniones`, y debe ser el contexto el que le de esa connotación de *"retroalimentación"* (Tus comentarios/críticas/observaciones/opiniones sobre mi X me ayudan a valorarlo, y posiblemente mejorarlo). También puedes usar `valoración`.

Creo que de todas opciones, `crítica` es la que mejor conserva el aspecto de *"circularidad"* que buscas, ya que los comentarios/opiniones/observaciones pueden ser positivos, negativos o incluso neutros, pero la *crítica* tiene la connotación de que es algo a lo que debes volver a prestar atención y posiblemente corregir. Por otro lado, por la misma razón `criticas` parece invitar a obtener sólo "negative feedback" cuando el "positive feedback" puede aportar información muy valiosa también. `Valoración` no anda demasiado lejos tampoco, así que yo creo que me decidiría por esta última.

> Por favor, dame tu valoración sobre este tema para que podamos mejorarlo
>
> <sub>Please provide me with some feedback on this topic so that we can improve.
>   .</sub>

Comment: En situaciones pedagógicas (por ejemplo, en cómo responder a un alumno que diga algo correcto/incorrecto), también simplemente «respuesta» puede servir aunque se suele usar en los artículos de pedagogía / lingüística aplicada simplemente «feedback» tal cual =/

Answer (score 3):

En tu caso yo iría más a **comentarios**, valoraciones.

> ¿Te ha gustado nuestra aplicación? Mándanos tus **comentarios** sobre cómo la mejorarías.

Esto me recuerda a un profesor que tuve que siempre decía al final:

> ¿Algún comentario, duda o sugerencia?

Dado que viene a colación de esta pregunta, he leído un [artículo en El pais](http://blogs.elpais.com/defensor-del-lector/2013/11/anglicismos-y-traducciones.html), donde se menciona esta frase:

> ¨... y para “feedback” existen en español palabras como valoración, evaluación, etc.¨

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer:  Dado que no aprobaron mi edición del otro comentario por ser demasiado larga y otras miasmas y a pesar de que no estoy de acuerdo con agregar respuestas a posts viejos que ya tienen respuesta aprobada voy a incluir mi respuesta (Me costó tiempo escribirla)

Creo que lo más cercano sería **Retroalimentación**

Si bien **Retroalimentación** no es aceptada por la RAE, es altamente utilizada en ámbitos técnicos y académicos (desde la ingeniería y sistemas hasta las ciencias exactas y naturales). La palabra más cercana es Realimentación, aceptada por la RAE, y ofrecida como sinónimo en varios sitios. El prefijo "re" me deja bastante que desear ya que la idea que se quiere comunicar es que el sistema es alimentado nuevamente "desde atrás".

El sistema más simple de feedback loop (negativo) sería:

A produce B y B inhibe A. De esta forma el feedback se establece desde "atrás hacia adelante" y por eso "retro" cobra sentido como en cualquier proceso retrógrado. Cuando uno realimenta un sistema, no queda claro desde donde lo hace o si la fuente de alimentación es externa o inherente al sistema.

Ver http://definicion.de/retroalimentacion/

Ante la propuesta de usar "feedback" directamente, se sostienen las mismas críticas. "Feedback no es una palabra aceptada". Pienso que entra en el criterio colectivo de los hablantes. Si todos estamos de acuerdo con que "feedback" o "retroalimentación" son palabras que significan lo que significan y sirven para comunicarnos, luego sería bueno usarlas.

Finalmente, dado que feedback no siempre se usa como retroalimentación positiva/negativa, las propuestas en relación a  **"devolución, comentario, crítica, etc"** son más que válidas.

Comment: ¿Existe alguna referencia que diga que la RAE no acepta "retroalimentación"? El hecho de que no esté en el diccionario de la RAE no significa que no la acepten. Muchas palabras compuestas o derivadas de otra no están en el diccionario de la RAE por motivos prácticos de volúmen.

Answer (score 1):

Un conocido en México que trabajaba en la fábrica de Volkswagen me comentó (esto fue hace más de 30 años) que le enseñaron a preguntar al equipo que dirijía

> Denme *feedback*, muchachos, denme *feedback*.

Si mando un email a un colaborador y quiero pedir *feedback* acerca de un borrador, por ejemplo, podría decir

> Feedback about this draft would be much appreciated.

Pero yo en lo personal prefiero decir

> Let me know your thoughts about this draft.

Por lo tanto, si uno no quiere usar el anglicismo, *feedback*, propondría decir

> Déjame saber tu **reacción** a mi borrador.

(Traducción informal: *Let me know what you think about my draft*.)

De hecho la BBC ahora pone un prólogo a su podcast "Newshour":

> Let us know what you think.

Lo cual es un indicio que "feedback" está cayendo de moda en inglés en peticiones directas.  Sin embargo, se sigue usando para hablar de la reacción solicitada o proporcionada, por ejemplo "Based on your feedback, I made a new version."  Esto se podría expresar así:

> En base a tus **comentarios**, hice una nueva versión.